# How to remove everything from the left side IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I need to reduce the window for the code in IntelliJ IDEA, and I would like to completely remove the left column, including the numbering of the lines and the rest of the hints.

I can remove line numbers:

[image: SCR Line number]

How to remove these tips?

[image: SCR How to remove?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings | Editor | General | Gutter Icons | [ ] Show gutter icons

Answer (score 2):

Also Ctrl + Shift + A: Toggle Distraction Free Mode